# Choose VFS with DBD::SQLite

Tags: perl, sqlite, vfs

Sqlite interface provides the following function:

```
int sqlite3_open_v2(
  const char *filename,   /* Database filename (UTF-8) */
  sqlite3 **ppDb,         /* OUT: SQLite db handle */
  int flags,              /* Flags */
  const char *zVfs        /* Name of VFS module to use */
);
```

I did not see anywhere in `DBD::SQLite` a way to pass the name of the vfs module to use, so I guess it chooses a default VFS module to work with.

Is there a way to do so in `DBD::SQLite`?

Answer (score -1):

If your SQLite is new enough, you can use a [URI filename](http://www.sqlite.org/uri.html):

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=file:/path/file?vfs=whatever");
```

Comment: DBD::SQLite installs it own version of sqlite (3.7.17) in a local dir. It doesn't use the default version installed in the system. It doesn't work.